# Getting cookie in react js

Tags: reactjs, cookies, webview

We set cookie with `key=test` and `value=cookie_value` for a WebView in android and we used code below to print cookies in `PHP`.

```
if($_COOKIE) {
   foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$val)
   {
       echo $key.' is '.$val."<br>\n";
   }
}
else
{
    echo "No Cookies are Set";    
}
```

Everything was right and script printed : `test is cookie_value`
Then we tried for `react-js` following :

`import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';`

Then i tried following to get cookies:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
const[cookie, setCookie] = useState(cookies.get('test'))
```

It doesn't work in react and my question is how can i get these cookies that have set in android native webview in react js page.

Comment: Does document.cookie display the cookies that you set?

Comment: @Oscar it shows undefined!

Comment: Then your issue is not with getting the cookie, there is no cookie to get. Is your PHP code being run on the same host as your react application?

Comment: @Oscar No. PHP code works correct and shows the cookie.

Comment: Cookies are tied to the host. If your react and PHP code are running on different hosts then react will not be able to access the cookie.

Comment: @Oscar Yessss! fixed. Thank you dear oscar